# Representations of Finite Groups and Weak Containment

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, finite-groups, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let $\pi : G \to U(\mathcal{H})$ and $\rho : G \to U(\mathcal{K})$ be irreducible unitary representations. If $\pi$ is weakly contained in $\rho$, then $\pi$ is contained in $\rho$.

I am allowed to use the following fact:

> If $\pi$ and $\rho$ are inequivalent irreducible representations of $G$, then $tr \circ \pi$ and $tr \circ \rho$ are orthogonal functions in $\ell^2(G)$.

So, arguing contrapositively, if $\pi$ is not contained in $\rho$, then there is no isometry $V : \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{K}$ such that $V \pi ( \cdot ) V^* = \rho (\cdot)$. In particular, it means that there is no unitary operator with the stated property, so $\pi$ and $\rho$ are unitarily inequivalent representations. Hence, $tr \circ \pi$ and $tr \circ \rho$ are orthogonal functions in $\ell^2(G)$. But I'm having trouble seeing how this implies that $\pi$ is not weakly contained in $\rho$.

Comment: Are both irrducible or just $\pi$? (if both are irreducible, then containment would imply equality)

Comment: Another question: are you able to use that $\pi \prec \rho$, when $\pi$ is irreducible, implies that the matrix coefficients of $\pi$ are pointwise limits of coefficients of $\rho$ (that makes the calculation simpler).

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez Yes, I believe we are allowed to assume that $\pi$ and $\rho$ are irreducible. Btw, what exactly do you mean by "coefficients" of a representation?

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez Also, what do you mean by equality? Do you mean that they are unitarily equivalent? How could they literally be equal if $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ are different Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't received the notification. By the coefficients of $\pi$ i mean the functions $g \mapsto \langle \eta, \pi(g) \xi \rangle$, where $\xi, \eta \in \mathcal{H}$, which are sometimes called "matrix coefficients". Yes, i mean unitary equivalence.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez I don't see how they are pointwise limits. From the definition of weak containment, the most it seems I can conclude is that $\langle \pi (g) x,x \rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^{k_n}  \langle \rho (g) y_i^{(n)} , y_i^{(n)} \rangle$. But even if I can show pointwise limits hold, I don't see how to conclude that $\pi$ and $\rho$ are equivalent.